# Não consigo gravar documento XML (e nem XSL) em variável - JavaScript e jQuery

Tags: javascript

Primeira vez que tô fazendo uma pergunta, então desculpa se não estou seguindo alguma norma, mas preciso urgente saber como faço isso:

Tenho um documento XML e 3 XSL e tô montando um pequeno currículo que pode mostrar os dados gravados do XML em 3 visões diferentes (cada XSL é uma visão). No código JavaScript tá dando erro na hora de salvar na variável `xmlDoc` o documento de XML. O que faço?

```
var xmlDoc, xslComplete, xslPub, xslOr, docComp, docPub, docOr, xsltProcessorComplete, xsltProcessorPub, xsltProcessorOr;

function start(){
    xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
    xslComplete=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
    xslPub=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
    xslOr=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xslComplete.async = false;
    xslPub.async = false;
    xslOr.async = false;
    xmlDoc.load("curriculo.xml");
    xslComplete.load("completo.xsl");
    xslPub.load("publicacoes.xsl");
    xslOr.load("orientacoes.xsl");
    xsltProcessorComplete=new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessorPub=new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessorOr=new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessorComplete.importStylesheet(xslComplete);
    xsltProcessorPub.importStylesheet(xslPub);
    xsltProcessorOr.importStylesheet(xslOr);
    docComp = xsltProcessorComplete.transformToFragment(xmlDoc,document);   
    document.getElementById("htmlStart").appendChild(docComp);
}

function loadComplete(){
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("htmlStart");
    mainDiv.innerHTML = ""
    docComp = xsltProcessorComplete.transformToFragment(xmlDoc,document);
    document.getElementById("htmlStart").appendChild(docComp);
}

function loadPub(){
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("htmlStart");
    mainDiv.innerHTML = ""
    docPub = xsltProcessorPub.transformToFragment(xmlDoc,document);
    document.getElementById("htmlStart").appendChild(docPub);
}

function loadOr(){
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("htmlStart");
    mainDiv.innerHTML = ""
    docOr = xsltProcessorOr.transformToFragment(xmlDoc,document);
    document.getElementById("htmlStart").appendChild(docOr);
}
```

Quando eu debugo pelo Chrome, ele dá erro nessa linha (e para de executar):

```
xmlDoc.load("curriculo.xml");
```

O erro é que o `xmlDoc` não é uma função, por isso não se pode usar o load.

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver?